# Delete User Record from DB using Sorcery in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sorcery

How would one go about deleting a user from an active Rails application in production when one used Sorcery for authentication? User registration is controlled from a central point, so it would just be best to delete the user record in the database.

The app is deployed to Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special, just delete user, smth like: `User.find(id).destroy!`.